# Words for extra labels in a pie chart?

Tags: mathematics, programming, charts

Given a pie chart with standard title and data labels but with extra explanatory ones, are there words for the extra ones? Like in this example...

[image: Labeled pie chart]

- a. Title
- b. Data label
- c. ???
- d. Data label ?
- e. ???
- f. ???
- g. ???

Comment: Items f and g are the text in the slide. Other text not labels of the chart are text boxes of notes, comments, sidebars and such.

Comment: The *f* text should be edited (*our some data* is wrong).

Comment: @HippoSawrUs, what do you mean? The text and values are all just examples.

Comment: I guess it should be 'Based on our [some date] we found'?? IDK.

Answer (score 1):

For example:
a. Title
b. Data label
c. Data label definition
d. Data label
e. Data label definition
f. Data source
g. Conclusion

Provided suggestion is based on personal experience of pitching and lecturing, I can't provide any source)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Love it. I'll add a legend to our designs so it's clear what they are. These are good names for our internal use. I didn't expect there to be official ones for all of them. Yours are very logical. 

Comment: Happy to help! Also not sure about "official" names, but I had to use them and it was clear enough for people during my own presentations

Comment: Personally I would regard c as the label slnce it turns the data (number) into information. The actual quantity is, of course, useful and interesting but the purpose of a pie chart is to present proportions within a data set in an easily comprehended manner. Without the labels indicating what the numbers represent the chart is meaningless no matter how comprehensively and accurately the numbers and percentages are presented.